# add_custom_command from another target

Tags: c, cmake

I'm currently trying to setup a CMake project with two executables, one of which is a simple utility used to generate code for the other. Relevant bits of CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(lua2c lua2c.c)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT lcode.c COMMAND lua2c lcode.lua lcode.c MAIN_DEPENDENCY lua2c)
...
add_executable(darpem ... lcode.c)
```

With this setup, target `lua2c` winds up with no dependencies, which causes `cc` to complain about no input files. If I remove the `add_custom_command` line, then `lua2c` is built properly, but obviously doesn't generate the file `lcode.c`. Is this possible in CMake? Would I need to add a subdirectory dependency of sorts?

Using CMake version 2.8.1 on Ubuntu 13.04, x86-64.

**NOTE:** For my particular case, because `lua2c` is simple enough, I can use a different language. I am, however, still curious as to how this might be possible (for more complex setups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation :

> Note that **MAIN_DEPENDENCY** is completely optional and is used as a suggestion to visual studio about where to hang the custom command.

Maybe this should solve your problem :

```
add_executable(lua2c lua2c.c)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT lcode.c COMMAND lua2c lcode.lua lcode.c DEPENDS lua2c)
#                                                                 ^^^^^^^
...
add_executable(darpem ... lcode.c)
```

Or if it doesn't work, this one should work :

```
add_executable(lua2c lua2c.c)
add_custom_command(TARGET lua2c
                    POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND lua2c lcode.lua lcode.c )

...
add_executable(darpem ... lcode.c)
add_dependencies( darpem lua2c )
```

It simply add a post build event after the build of `lua2c`. And it add `lua2c` as a dependency of `darpem`.

Comment: I still don't see how that affects the dependencies of `lua2c` itself, unless CMake is optimizing it out, but this works - thanks!

Comment: @DrewMcGowen In your example, the command was executed during the `lua2c` build. So at this time the lua2c binary does not exist. That why you have to add dependencies somewhere to force the build of lua2c before anything else.